# Как получить переменную из массива JSON rapidjson

Tags: c++, json

Не могу получить переменную `"id"` Пример JSON:

```
{
"response": [{
"id": 1,
"name": "ВКонтакте API",
"screen_name": "apiclub",
"is_closed": 0,
"type": "group",
"is_admin": 1,
"admin_level": 3,
"is_member": 1
}
```

Выдает ошибку: `Assertion failed: IsObject(), file ...\rapidjson-master\include\rapidjson\document.h, line 1344`

Код:

```
int getIdGroop(std::string GroupName) {
    Document documentJson;
    std::string formedLink = LINK_TO_THE_API_SERVER + "groups.getById?group_ids=" + GroupName + "&access_token=" + ACCESS_TOKEN + "&v=" + VERSION_API ,readBuffer;
    int IdOfGroup = 1;
    
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode response;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, formedLink.c_str());
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);     //Отключение проверки SSL сертификата
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    response = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    //curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    if (documentJson.Parse(readBuffer.c_str()).HasParseError())
        std::cout << "error " << std::endl;
    documentJson.Parse(readBuffer.c_str());
    const Value& valueResponse = documentJson["response"];
    std::cout << valueResponse["id"].GetInt() << std::endl;

    return IdOfGroup;
}
```

Comment: response - это массив, а id  содержится в объекте - первом элементе

Comment: @user7860670 А как достать из объекта id число (int)

Answer (score 0):

Не заметил что `response` это массив объектов ( `[{}]` ), так что нужно указывать `[0]`

```
const Value& valueResponse = documentJson["response"];
            return documentJson["response"][0]["id"].GetInt();
```